# How Do I Select Canister Rounds in Tanks in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've acquired the canister unlock for the T-90 tanks in Battlefield 3 but have no idea how to switch from the default selected rounds, HE?, to any other options.  I thought it might be the V key but that doesn't seem to do it.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1 and 2 keys (PC, not sure about the console controls) activate your main weapon and secondary weapon, respectively.  This is of course the same in tanks (or any vehicle with a secondary weapon, for that matter) as on foot.  The main weapon in the tanks is always the tank's main gun.

You select what your secondary weapon will be in the customize menu.

Comment: On consoles, it's the same as change weapon (Y on 360).

Comment: Thanks very much, that got me to the correct place to set it up.  Many thanks.